# SQL query to combine the results from two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016

I have these two tables and I want to build a SQL query:

[image]

My search criteria is:

- **Name** (in field `Brother` and field `Speaker`)
- **Congregation** (in field `Congregation` in both tables)

I want the resulting view to be a single list of all records, sorted by date (fields `Talk Date` and `Last Given`).

So:

- Away Talks

I am interesting in this info:

Talk Date, Talk Number, Congregation, Brother

- Home Talks

Last Given, Talk Number, Congregation, Speaker

I would like to pull the above two sets of results into a single list sorted by the date column.

I started to do a SQL query in Access 2016 but am lost!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
select [Talk Date], [Talk Number], Congregation, Brother as Speaker
from [Away Talks]
union all
select [Last Given], [Talk Number], Congregation, Speaker
from [Home Talks]
order by [Talk Date]
```

Comment: Thanks. And how would this be adjusted to be able to state that the name needs to be xyz and the congregation abc?

Comment: If I add "WHERE" to each of those select queries then it yeilds the results I want. Thanks.